# quasi random number generator for gaussian process

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to evolve a variable (say X staring value of 1) for 1200 time steps following a lognormal process (i.e. `X_t = X_(t-1) exp( drift * dt + sigma*GaussianRandom*sqrt(dt))` ). I want to use quasi random numbers to obtain faster convergence.

My understanding is I need a 1200 dimensional quasi random number generator. At each time step I use X_t to compute some other variables, hence I need all the 1200 points, I cannot jump to a single terminal point and reduce the dimensionality.

My questions are :

1. At such high dimension will I have any advantage using quasi random numbers vs pseudo random numbers.
2. Can someone please point me to some C++ code which can help me with the quasi random number generation.

Answer (score 1):

> At such high dimension will I have any advantage using quasi random numbers vs pseudo random numbers.

1200 is not a high dimension compared to a good pseudo random number generator. What you need is a good pseudo random number generator, and that pretty much excludes `rand()`.

> Can someone please point me to some C++ code which can help me with the quasi random number generation.

This question implicitly assumes you can't use a PRNG. You can, so long as it has a very long repeat and exhibits very good behavior. Mersenne twister will more than suffice for your needs (but there are even better ones nowadays). There are implementations of MT galore, but if you can use C++11, MT is built-in to the language. The easiest way to solve this is to use the C++11 random number generators. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random .

Comment: sorry my question may not be clear. I am not looking for a psuedo random numbers but i am looking for a quasi random number generator like sobol.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an answer to your first question.

For the second one: have a look at the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-algorithms.html#Random-number-generator-algorithms). The code is in C and well structured, so you can easily write a wrapper class around (if needed).

I would take the gsl_rng_mt19937 or gsl_rng_ranlxd2 and modify them. I prefer the gsl_rng_ranlxd2 (If computational time does not meter).

Comment: I would never use GSL. The level of convolution in that code makes Boost look simple.